# How can I sort a 2d array according to its integer value?

Tags: python, sorting

I would like to sort each integer value in ascending order and have each P value move along with it.

Input:

```
[['P1', 168], ['P2', 146], ['P3', 116], ['P4', 113], ['P5', 113], ['P6', 90], ['P7', 28]]
```

Output:

```
[['P7', 28],['P6', 90],['P4', 113], ['P5', 113],['P3', 116], ['P2', 146], ['P1', 168]]
```

Comment: What have your tried so far? Show us your work and tell us where you are stuck. Stackoverflow isn't for getting your homework answers

Comment: Sorry, second time posting ever. Was not aware of how specific I should be with what I have. As this is now marked as a duplicate I believe changing it is redundant. But thank you for providing me with more insight into how I might better my future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For

```
a=[['P1', 168], ['P2', 146], ['P3', 116], ['P4', 113], ['P5', 113], ['P6', 90], ['P7', 28]]
```

One solution could be:

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.sort(a, axis=-1, kind=None, order=None)
a1[:,[0,1]] = a1[:,[1,0]][::-1] <=========== [::-1] to reverse the order
a1
```

Output:

[image]